# Java Timer vs ExecutorService?

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, executorservice

I have code where I schedule a task using `java.util.Timer`. I was looking around and saw `ExecutorService` can do the same. So this question here, have you used `Timer` and `ExecutorService` to schedule tasks, what is the benefit of one using over another?

Also wanted to check if anyone had used the `Timer` class and ran into any issues which the `ExecutorService` solved for them.

Comment: And if you need something even more featurefull, check out [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). It gives you a great deal more job control, including cron like scheduling, cluster-aware scheduling, individualized control over jobs (concepts such as one run at a time, dependencies, etc). --Tim

Answer (score 358, accepted):

According to [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/):

- `Timer` can be sensitive to changes in the system clock, `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` isn't.
- `Timer` has only one execution thread, so long-running task can delay other tasks. `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` can be configured with any number of threads. Furthermore, you have full control over created threads, if you want (by providing `ThreadFactory`).
- Runtime exceptions thrown in `TimerTask` kill that one thread, thus making `Timer` dead :-( ... i.e. scheduled tasks will not run anymore. `ScheduledThreadExecutor` not only catches runtime exceptions, but it lets you handle them if you want (by overriding `afterExecute` method from `ThreadPoolExecutor`). Task which threw exception will be canceled, but other tasks will continue to run.

If you can use `ScheduledThreadExecutor` instead of `Timer`, do so.

One more thing... while `ScheduledThreadExecutor` isn't available in Java 1.4 library, there is a [Backport of JSR 166 (`java.util.concurrent`) to Java 1.2, 1.3, 1.4](http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/), which has the `ScheduledThreadExecutor` class.

Comment: Another advantage: if you like lambda expression, Timer cannot use them. ScheduledExecutorService can accept lambda expression because the args it takes is "Runnable" and not "TimerTask".

Answer (score 68):

If it's available to you, then it's difficult to think of a reason *not* to use the Java 5 executor framework. Calling:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

will give you a `ScheduledExecutorService` with similar functionality to `Timer` (i.e. it will be single-threaded) but whose access may be slightly more scalable (under the hood, it uses concurrent structures rather than complete synchronization as with the `Timer` class). Using a `ScheduledExecutorService` also gives you advantages such as:

- You can customize it if need be (see the `newScheduledThreadPoolExecutor()` or the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` class)
- The 'one off' executions can return results

About the only reasons for sticking to `Timer` I can think of are:

- It is available pre Java 5
- A similar class is provided in J2ME, which could make porting your application easier (but it wouldn't be terribly difficult to add a common layer of abstraction in this case)

Comment: Another reason for using `TimerTask` may be the availability of `scheduledExecutionTime()` method which doesn't seem to have any equivalent in `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: Another note: I am writing this comment in 2k17, there is no more J2ME. it is already dead.

Answer (score 30):

ExecutorService is newer and more general.  A timer is just a thread that periodically runs stuff you have scheduled for it.

An ExecutorService may be a thread pool, or even spread out across other systems in a cluster and do things like one-off batch execution, etc...

Just look at what each offers to decide.

Answer (score 10):

From Oracle documentation page on [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

> A **ThreadPoolExecutor** that can additionally schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically. This class is preferable to **Timer** when multiple worker threads are needed, or when the additional flexibility or capabilities of ThreadPoolExecutor (which this class extends) are required.

`ExecutorService/ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` is obvious choice when you have multiple worker threads.

Pros of `ExecutorService` over `Timer`

1. `Timer` can't take advantage of available CPU cores unlike  `ExecutorService` especially with multiple tasks using flavours of `ExecutorService` like [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)
2. `ExecutorService` provides collaborative API if you need coordination between multiple tasks. Assume that you have to submit N number of worker tasks and wait for completion of all of them. You can easily achieve it with [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) API. If you want to achieve the same with multiple `Timer` tasks, it would be not simple.
3. [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) provides better API for management of Thread life cycle.

   > Thread pools address two different problems: they usually provide improved performance when executing large numbers of asynchronous tasks, due to reduced per-task invocation overhead, and they provide a means of bounding and managing the resources, including threads, consumed when executing a collection of tasks. Each ThreadPoolExecutor also maintains some basic statistics, such as the number of completed tasks

   Few advantages:

   a. You can create/manage/control life cycle of Threads & optimize thread creation cost overheads

   b. You can control processing of tasks ( Work Stealing, ForkJoinPool, invokeAll) etc.

   c. You can monitor the progress and health of threads

   d. Provides better exception handling mechanism

Answer (score 6):

My reason for sometimes preferring Timer over Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() is that I get much cleaner code when I need the timer to execute on daemon threads.

compare

```
private final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    }
};
private final ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(threadFactory);
```

with

```
private final Timer timer = new Timer(true);
```

I do this when I don't need the robustness of an executorservice.

Answer (score 2):

I did had an issue with Timer and I replaced it *with ScheduledExecutorService* to fix it.

The issue was the *Timer* depends on System time and everytime I change it, it affects the functioning of the application. So I replaced the *Timer* with *ScheduledExecutorService* and now it is working fine.