# Using Timer with Swing vs Thread sleep

Tags: java, swing

I am building a Swing application in Java.
I've read that in order to run a GUI task periodically it is recommended to use a `Timer` object (from javax.swing package). I am trying to understand what is the difference between using the `Timer` object vs using the `sleep` method for the Thread. Don't they both achieve the same?

Meir

Comment: Read the answer provided on this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416893/executorservice-vs-swing-timer/417015#417015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sleep the EDT your entire GUI will hang and become unresponsive until the thread wakes up. This is bad.