# How to make thread run something every x seconds? (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

I have a program, in there I have this thread which will recieve Strings from another user and save them in another object. I want to make this thread run the "seek for Strings and save them-method" every x seconds. How do I do that?

Comment: Have a look at TimerTask

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29

Comment: Do as @assylias suggests: use a `ScheduledExecutorService`. It is _much_ better than a `Timer{,Task}` combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this answer would be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12908477/3328790

The user suggests you use Timer and TimerTask classes which you can use to schedule your task to run every n seconds.

Comment: As commented above, using a `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` is a much better solution than a `Timer`/`TimerTask` arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Runnable` which would be used in your periodically running `Thread` and create another `Runnable` which will start the needed `Thread` in conform of your needs. Start the second `Thread`.