# Print 60 seconds countdown in Java

Tags: java, jframe, seconds

I've searched everywhere for some simple code to print 60 seconds down, say on a JFrame constructor. So when a JFrame is run, the window title will be shown a countdown from 60-0 seconds (which in my case will shutdown). - No need for code to shutdown.

Something on the lines of:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window will terminate in: " + java.util.Calendar.SECOND);
```

Of course the code above does not make sense because it's printing the current time second. But you get the idea.

Comment: searched everywhere? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908412/print-hello-world-every-x-seconds second result on google

Comment: Yup I seen that one already, but that prints something every x seconds, it's different to what I'm looking for

Comment: But you can easily adapt it for your needs. Send notification every one second and there you are!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `TimerTask` to set the title of the `JFrame` every second.

```
public class TimerFrame {
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimerFrame timerFrame = new TimerFrame();
        timerFrame.frame.setVisible(true);
        timerFrame.frame.setSize(400,100);
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){

            int second = 60;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setTitle("Application will close in " + second-- + " seconds.");
            }   
        },0, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I got this error when trying to compile the code: [code] error: constructor Timer in class Timer cannot be applied to given types;
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
        ^
  required: int,ActionListener
  found: no arguments

Comment: I am using JDK6 and it works fine.  Did you copy the code or type it out?  What JDK are you using?  Make sure you are using `java.util.Timer`

Answer (score 4):

Just create a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and have a counter initialized at 60.

Set up the timer to be called every second.

Each time reduce the count by one and update the text.

When you reach 0 do whatever you do for the end of the countdown and stop the timer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int count = 60;
while(count != 0){
        try {
            countlabel.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            count--;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, It's not a good practice to use `Thread.sleep` because it will freezes the frame until finishes, suppose the delay is `5` seconds, it'll freezes the frame for 5 seconds. Instead use `SwingTimer`, see `Tim B`'s answer.