# Telling Java Servlet to "executeQuery" every 5seconds

Tags: java, sql, executequery

Is it possible to execute a query in my java servlet every 5 seconds? As i need the data values inside my database to update my bar graph in my website every few seconds.

```
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStr);
```

Comment: Easier to refresh your web page every 5 seconds through Javascript.

Comment: **Timer and TimerTask**

Refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908412/print-hello-world-every-x-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStr);
        }
```

You can Try this.
Moreover, I am not sure what's your complete requirement here is.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a javascript function for polling. Let's suppose the function is called `poll`. Then, you can do it like this:

```
var polling = function(interval) {
    poll();
    setTimeout(polling, interval);
};
```