# Invalidate in Thread Every X Seconds

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So I have a thread that is instantiated inside a view. The thread should call `postInvalidate()` to redraw the screen every 16 milliseconds (60fps). The screen never redraws itself, though. It just remains blank. What am I doing wrong? Code is below:

```
 public class DrawingView extends View {
    private Paint paint;
    private GraphicsLoop gThread;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        gThread = new GraphicsLoop();
        gThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         // Draw Stuff
    }
}
```

Thread:

```
public class GraphicsLoop extends Thread {
        private long frameTime;

        GraphicsLoop(){
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                long frameTimeDelta = System.currentTimeMillis() - frameTime;
                if (frameTimeDelta > 16) {
                    frameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    postInvalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void start ()
        {
            frameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you assume that every loop execution takes 1 ms?

Comment: I guess the problem is because of your highly indiscernible time of 16 milliseonds ..Try to use around 5 seconds and see if you still face issue ..

Comment: Changing the time value doesn't make a difference.

Comment: How you are starting your Thread ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a call to `super.start()` in the overriden `start()` method in `GraphicsLoop`, thus the thread is never started.

Comment: This was it. Thanks alot!

Comment: This may have solved your problem but I presume you have many other issues and the top most is you are using a WHILE loop, it increases your CPU utilization like anything. Read about why you not use WHILE loop for recurring tasks. You should infact use Java's build in support for these kind of recurring tasks - read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908412/print-hello-world-every-x-seconds, answer by @Tim Bender