# How to make my clock like this 03:05:01

Tags: java

I have project in java.

> Create CTime class with the following specifications
>
> 1. Attributes: Hour, minute and second
> 2. Hour >=0 and <= 23, minute >=0 and <=59 , second >=0 and <= 59
> 3. Methods
>
>    - Constructor that updates the CTime attributes
>    - `set` and `get` methods for each attribute
>    - `tick` method that add 1 second to the CTime object and returns nothing
>    - `toString` method that creates time string with the following format HH:mm:ss e.g. 22:15:01

and I did this

```
public class CTime {

    int hour;
    int min;
    int sec;

    public CTime(int h, int m, int s) {
        hour = h;
        min = m;
        sec = s;
    }

    public void setHour(int h) {
        hour = h;
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public void setMin(int m) {
        min = m;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setSec(int s) {
        sec = s;
    }

    public int getSec() {
        return sec;
    }

    public void tick() {
        sec++;
        if (sec >= 59) {
            sec = 0;
            min++;
            if (min >= 59) {
                min = 0;
            }
            hour++;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
        return s;
    }
}
```

How to make my hour and min and sec with 2 digit, e.g. 05:02:09?

And my code is it correct or not?

Comment: Just use [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on doing this kind of stuff with Strings the way you are, you could do something like the following:

```
public String toString() {
    String s =  (hour > 9 ? hour : "0" + hour) + ":" + (min > 9 ? min : "0" + min) + ":" + (sec > 9 ? sec : "0" + sec);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what are you doing

Comment: I'm using inline IF statements (not sure of the technical term for this type of statement) to determine whether or not a leading 0 is required in the output.  In simple terms, if hour, min, or sec is greater than 9 you will need a leading 0 on your output to maintain 2 digits in each section.  It simply determines if the output is single digit, if it is, it prepends a 0 to the line before appending the single digit value, so it will always be 2 digits.

Comment: That syntax is called a [ternary operator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). Just a compact version of an `if-then` statement.

Comment: @Mohannad Was my answer helpful to you?  If so, please mark it as the answer to your question.  It would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

```
public String toString() {
    String s = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, min, sec);
    return s;
}
```

One more link [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/)

And your code, yes it is correct. To make it a *live* clock, all you have to do is call `tick()` method every second. Take a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908412/print-hello-world-every-x-seconds/12908477#12908477) to learn how to do that.