# How to change variable every x second without stopping the program in Java?

Tags: java, console

Iam new here, like week ago I started learning to program and Iam working on my text based strategic game in which I would like to make resources gather every x seconds passively.

basicaly my game is based on while (true) loop in which are switch cases and the game keeps waiting for keys to press to gather resources.

I would like the game to gather resources passively every x seconds.

example : every 10 seconds you will receive +1 wood.

I will welcome in help :)
Iam programming in java using NetBeansIDE

Answer (score 0):

Just get the current time in every loop run with [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())
and check whether the 10 seconds passed since last time you gave +1 wood.
Note the time unit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are storing gathered resources, but if you could call a method to look it up based on when the game began. You could store the following variable as part of your game class:

```
private long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And then get current resources by using the following method:

```
public int getWood() {
    long diffMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    int numSeconds = (int)diffMilliseconds / 1000;
    int amtWood = numSeconds/10;
    return amtWood + <any other wood gathering/calculating parameters>;
}
```

This does not account for using your wood. If you want a variable to update every ten seconds, you could use something like the solution here: [Print "hello world" every X seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908412/print-hello-world-every-x-seconds). This solution uses the TimeTask class. Rather than printing, you could update a amtWood variable.

Comment: thank you, I checked your link and this code works as I want, problem is that if I use wood = wood + 1; instead of system.out.Println .. it says local variables referenced from inner class must be final or effectively final , maybe the problem is that my resources are stored as an integer?

class SayHello extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
       System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
    }
}

// And From your main() method or any other method
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 0, 5000);

Comment: Don't make wood a local variable, make it an instance or class variable. You can declare private int wood; under your class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no restrictions on what classes you can use, try `Timer` class available as part of Java Swing. You can also look at `java.util.Timer` class for scheduling your updates.