# Continuously running function altering TextView

Tags: java, android

I have a `TextView` on my splash screen and I'm trying to emulate Discord's randomized loading text.

I have the following code, pulled from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12908467/4664094):

```
    private void LoadText() {

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final TextView loadingTextView = findViewById(R.id.loading);
            loadingTextView.setText(FetchRandomLoadingText());
        }
    };


    ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

`FetchRandomLoadingText()` returns a string from an `ArrayList` by index, works fine (tested with `Toast` to make sure it wasn't the problem).

This is working fine for *one or two* updates, but if the splash takes longer (slow internet connection for example) to do its thing, the text stops updating after **2 iterations**.

I've looked at the equivalent of `setInterval` in JavaScript for Java but the solutions seems to iterate once and then stop all together.

Am I missing something obvious in getting this to endlessly run until I flag for a new Activity to be loaded?

Comment: Are you sure about FetchRandomLoadingText? May it return same data after 2 iterations?

Comment: There's a large enough data set for it to be unlikely, but I see what you're saying. I've had it running on my S8 for about 5 minutes now and the text hasn't changed past the 2nd iteration's updated text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a handler instead of a scheduler.

```
long delay = 5000; //5 seconds
final TextView loadingTextView = findViewById(R.id.loading);
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadingTextView.setText(FetchRandomLoadingText());
        handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
};
handler.post(runnable);
```

I would also test to make sure FetchRandomLoadingText() runs like you expect it to. Maybe run it 20 times and print the results in a dummy activity

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's code is what I've been using in production but with a slight change. I did some profiling on the code during execution and noticed a slight memory leak if my splash screen didn't change to the main activity (by design when I found the bug). I left the above code running for around 20 minutes by mistake, and found that the app began running 10s of `mb` over what should be realistic for a simple Activity with a `TextView`.

The altered, memory leak free code should have `handler` and `runnable` declared at a class level and instantiated in the `onCreate` function, rather than inside the local execution block. Doing so not only prevents the memory leak, but also executes faster.