# Will this pause my Java thread for a minute?

Tags: java, calendar

Am I doing something really stupid here? I am trying to execute a method every minute or so, forever, or until I stop the program.

```
    while(true) {
        this.doSomethingPeriodically();
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int minutes = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int resume = minutes + 1;
        while (now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < resume) {
            // waiting for a minute
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This code will never leave the loop. It's an endless loop, since the `Calendar` instance refered to by `now` won't change.

Also, what you try to do here is implement [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) which is a very bad idea (it uses CPU time doing nothing interesting).

The correct way to sleep is to use `Thread.`[`sleep()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)).

Comment: So, if I had a new Calendar instance, it'd work? But I should use sleep() anyway, huh?

Comment: Yes to both ;-) If you assigned a new Calendar instance to now inside the loop then it would work (provided you don't enter the loop in minute 59 of the hour ;-)), but you should use sleep() instead anyway.

Comment: Understood. I would reinventing the wheel, and making it square instead of round, so to speak. Thanks!

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, Thread.sleep() will pause your thread for *at least* a minute (and not necessarily exactly one minute).

Comment: Using sleep, you just leaves the "CPU" and became available from the "stop point + 1 line" after the sleep time.

In teh case of that loop, your code only work inside that loop. Use java.util.Time and java.util.TimerTask for a clear code.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the Timer class instead. It's meant for this sort of thing:

- http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=54
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Edit:
I just read that there's a newer replacement for Timer: ExecutorService. I've never used it, but it seems to have some advantages:

- http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html
- [Java Timer vs ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice)

Answer (score 4):

the simplest way for execute tasks repeteadly in java is the java.util.TimerTask and java.util.Timer api.

A simple code is:

```
public class PrinterTimerTask extends java.util.TimerTask {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println( 'Current time is: ' + System.nanoTime() );
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long delay = 0;
    long period = 60000;
    java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer(threadName);
    PrinterTimerTask task = new PrinterTimerTask();
    timer = new Timer("SomeThreadNameForProfiler");
    timer.schedule( task, delay, period );
  }
}
```

Variables:
    task - task to be scheduled.
    delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.
    period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.

More info:
Timer and TimerTask javadoc:
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Another example:
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=54

[]'s,

And Past

Answer (score 3):

Try using sleep instead, as it won't cause the processor to continue working on the thread:

[Thread.sleep()](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

```
    while(true) {
            this.doSomethingPeriodically();
            Thread.sleep(60000);
    }
```

Comment: You should not extend Thread (implement Runnable instead) and you should not reference static methods (such as Thread.sleep()) via a reference.

Comment: I would also say that it is generally a better idea to use a short sleep time and rather repeat it and check if we should stop.

Comment: @Svish, that's what `InterruptedException` is for.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use a [Timer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or at least use a [sleep](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29).

Comment: example TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(4);

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do here is called [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_wait). You are unnecessarily using huge amounts of CPU time (and you would even be using unnecessary memory if you fixed your bug and created a new Calendar instance in each loop).

What you actually want is the method [`Thread.sleep()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), it is pretty well explained in a [tutorial on sun.com](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the sleep function: `CurrentThread.sleep()` and you specify the number of milliseconds that you want as a delay. It's better than busy waiting...

Comment: The exact syntax is: Thread.currentThread().sleep(delay);            In the parameter you specify the delay in msec...

Comment: `sleep` being a static method, it is good practice to call it on the class: `Thread.sleep(...);`.