# Alternatives to Quartz for job scheduling

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

Has anyone found any alternative open-source solutions to Quartz which they are happy with?

I know Cronacle is a well respected (and pricey) closed source solution for job scheduling but I'd like to make sure we exhaust the open-source alternatives before going down that route.

Comment: Whats wrong with Quartz?

Comment: @cletus: It has a poorly designed API, it's buggy, and a pig to set up for all but simple configurations. I'd love an alternative, but I've yet to find one.

Comment: We're choosing to make due with Quartz for now.  There are more pressing issues for us to deal with and Quartz is the devil we already know.

Our stop-gap solution involved breaking our jobs up into three separate Quartz instances which means three separate sets of Quartz tables in the DB.  Ugly, but it works -- AND is listed as technical debt to be addressed.

Comment: @cclark we were using four separate sets of tables. Now we are going do use quartz to do the minimal work it should do (as a timer).We will handle job state ourselves. What about your progress? Anything worth sharing? thx!

Comment: @han-zheng I have moved on from that project. Separating the tables was working, but it certainly was pretty. As far as I know it still persists that way today.

Comment: @cclark Have you ever found solution to this?

Comment: One limitaiton with Quartz in clustered mode:

Quartz uses JDBC connections to operate in clustered mode. If the application is distributed, runing in multiple containers it will require multiple JDBC connection. In most of the cases SQL servers are shared accross the services which limits the number of JDBC connections a service can make withe the SQL server.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Did you already check all of those listed in [Open Source Job Schedulers in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/job-schedulers):

1. jcrontab
2. Quartz
3. Fulcrum Scheduler
4. Essiembre J2EE Scheduler
5. Gos4j
6. Oddjob
7. Job Scheduler
8. JDRing
9. jBatchEngine
10. MyBatchFramework
11. Super
12. cron4j

Comment: I'd like to share an answer which goes more into detail and contains descriptions of these libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1499047/840405

Comment: I upvoted because it answers briefly to the question. But would be better with a small description or some kind of comparison against Quartz.

Comment: @jitter which among these would you recommend to use?

Answer (score 7):

I did some looking a while back and was hard-pressed to find any open source Java-based job scheduler that seemed to have even a fraction of the reputation and usage of Quartz.  I would be really curious to hear why Quartz isn't sufficient.

Comment: Sorry to comment on an old post, but I wanted other users to understand some of the issues with Quartz.  The big one for us is volatile and non-durable jobs and triggers.  We have a mix of both and they are essential to our system.  Quartz has many bugs around volatility and durability, and this comment from James House regarding volatile jobs and triggers is troubling: "The entire notion of volatility is removed with Quartz 2.0. No one uses the feature. If you do have need for non-persisted scheduling data, use a RAMJobStore."

Comment: Quartz uses JDBC connections to operate in clustered mode. If the application is distributed, runing in multiple containers it will require multiple JDBC connection. In most of the cases SQL servers are shared accross the services which limits the number of JDBC connections a service can make withe the SQL server.

Answer (score -4):

What about Flux Scheduler (http://fluxcorp.com/)? Now http://flux.ly.

Comment: Btw, are there any (commercial) alternatives which include a visual dashboard helping the Ops team to analyse production issues?

Comment: -1 for the SPAM link to commercial site that doesn't provide anything related to the question. (Provide a more specific link if there is a project you refer to)

Comment: Extraordinarily buggy when we used it.