# Accessing running task scheduled with java.util.Timer

Tags: java, timer, task

I'm working on a Java project where I have created a class that looks like this (abridged version):

```
public class Daemon {
  private static Timer[] timerarray=null;
  private static Daemon instance=null;

  protected Daemon() {
    ArrayList<Timer> timers = new ArrayList<Timer>();
    Timer t = new Timer("My application");
    t.schedule(new Worker(), 10000,30000);
    timers.add(t);
    //...
    timerarray = timers.toArray(new Timer[]{});
  }
  public static Daemon getInstance() { 
    if(instance==null) instance=new Daemon(); 
    return instance;
  }
  public SomeClass getSomeValueFromWorker(int i) {
    if(timerarray==null || i>=timerarray.length) return null;
    /* 
     * **HOW TO ACCESS THE Worker INSTANCE IN THE Timer ARRAY HERE!? **
     */
    return theValue;
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////
  private class Worker extends TimerTask {
    public Worker() {}
    public void run() {
      // do some work
    }
    public SomeReturnClass someMethod(SomeType someParameter) {
      //
      return something;
    }
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

I start this class, e.g. by invoking `daemon.getInstance();`.

However, I'd like to have some way to access the running task objects' methods (for example, for monitoring the objects' state). 
The Java class `java.util.Timer` does not seem to provide the means to access the running object, it just schedules the object instance extending `TimerTask`.

Are there ways to access the "running" object instanciated within a `Timer`? Do I have to subclass the `Timer` class with the appropriate methods to somehow access the instance (this "feels" strange, somehow)? 
I suppose someone might have done this before ... where can I find examples of this "procedure"?

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Timer`. The [ScheduledExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) implementations are much better and provide the functionality you want with some extra work. See [409932](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice/409993#409993) for some reasons why to avoid `Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Daemon constructor, you can collect the instances of `Worker` into some kind of collection, and add a getter for that collection. This requires increasing the access level to the inner `Worker` class, as well as making sure that `Worker`'s methods are thread safe.

Another thing: Why do you create a new `Timer` per job? if your jobs finish quickly, and you don't have too many of them, consider registering all of them in a single `Timer`. As an alternative, use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), where you have a pool of threads of a size you choose.

Comment: I create a new Timer per job because each job does a lot of things underneath. I omitted what I thought was irrelevant for my question.