# Recursive loop Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, maven, selenium, recursion, junit

I have a test that loads a page and searches for an element. If it is not present, wait a time interval and then go back and search again. If the element is present output the text, and then wait a time interval and repeat the test.

My reason for my selenium script is to continually scrape a webpage from a console that displays amount of current viewers, and console out the variable saved every ~10 minutes. I want to do this recursively since the test will complete once it runs through one time. I want this to run as long as I want it to, and stop it at will. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
//Search for channel (Change below to a new channel)
            driver.findElement(By.id("channelName")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("channelName")).sendKeys("ch123");

//Label - updateViewer
        updateViewer();
//Verify that viewer count is listed
//Label checkViewer
        checkViewer();
//Once viewer is updated, loop back to updateViewer and below
        loopInterval();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void updateViewer() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Getting current viewer count");
        driver.findElement(By.id("gobutton")).click();
        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
            try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("//table[@id='datatable1']/tbody/tr/td[4]"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void checkViewer() throws InterruptedException {
        boolean viewElement = isElementPresent(By.xpath("//table[@id='datatable1']/tbody/tr/td[4]"));
        if(!viewElement){
            System.out.println("no view element, refreshing page");
            updateViewer();
        }
        else{
            String viewers = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='datatable1']/tbody/tr/td[4]")).getText();
            System.out.println(viewers);
            //-- placement to write current timestamp and date + viewers to file --

            // -- placement method that calls updateViewer and checkViewer in a loop --
        }
    }

    private void loopInterval() throws InterruptedException {
        updateViewer();
        checkViewer();
    }
```

Comment: Try using a [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any **recursion** here, only scheduled repetition. It would definitely simplify your code if your code became a task managed by a task scheduler, like a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). You could strip all the loops and sleeps from your code.

```
ScheduledExecutorService sched = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);  // single-threaded OK

final ScheduledFuture<?> future = sched.scheduleAtFixedRate( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (canDoStuffNow) {
            doStuffNow();
        }
        else {
            // Skip, wait another second
        }
    }
}, /* Delay for */ 0, /* Every */ 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

That will run reliably, at a fixed rate (every second) for as long as you need it to. Just call `future.cancel(true)` if you need to cancel it.

If you need different levels of delay, e.g. run every 1 second, but delay 10 seconds under some condition, you may of course add a `Thread.sleep(longer)` within the task body.

Comment: Before I read this, I tried to use a Timer and a TimerTask, but it appears that when running the script, it never reaches the timertask. Would you still recommend ScheduledExecutorService over a timertask?

Comment: Yes. Timer/TimerTask still works, but it's not ideal nowadays. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/409993/954442 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6111645/954442