# Is this how to schedule a java method to run 1 second later?

Tags: java, android

In my method, I want to call another method that will run 1 second later. This is what I have.

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
          MyMethod();
          Log.w("General", "This has been called one second later");
        timer.cancel();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Is this how it's supposed to be done? 
Are there other ways to do it since I'm on Android? 
Can it be repeated without any problems?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of a `Timer`, I'd recommend using a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

```
final ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

exec.schedule(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        MyMethod();
    }
}, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: The code I'm using doesn't happen in an activity, so I'm going with this one. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you recommend this over the Timer?

Comment: @Niek, [Timer vs. ExecutorService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice)

Comment: That's quite overkill...This answer should explain more about UI Thread and background job. If someone has time to improve it.

Answer (score 29):

There are several alternatives. But here is Android specific one.

If you thread is using `Looper` (and Normally all `Activity`'s, `BroadcastRecevier`'s and `Service`'s methods `onCreate`, `onReceive`, `onDestroy`, etc. are called from such a thread), then you can use `Handler`. Here is an example:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
     @Override
     public void run()
     {
         myMethod();
     }
}, 1000);
```

Note that you do not have to cancel anything here. This will be run only once on the same thread your Handler was created.

Comment: +1, this is a neat approach. I've never done anything with the Android platform, so this is probably the better approach. my answer is more generic.

Answer (score 2):

If you are *not* in UI thread, consider adding a very simple:

```
try
{
  Thread.sleep( 1000 );
}//try
catch( Exception ex)
{ ex.printStackTrace(); }//catch

//call your method
```

Answer (score 1):

ScheduledExecutorService or AsyncTask for UI related.

Note that if you are to update UI, that code should be posted to UI thread. as in [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) Guide

```
        final Bitmap bitmap = loadImageFromNetwork("http://example.com/image.png");
        mImageView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
```

There is also nice `postDelayed` method in `View`

```
    mImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_inactive);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

that will update UI after 1 sec.