# how to cancel a timer's existing schedule

Tags: android, timer, schedule

Currently I am using a timer to execute some function every interval time. However, later on when I want to change the interval of executing the function, I cannot cancel the previous schedule. how this can be solved? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean "i cannot cancel the previous schedule"? do you not know how to do it, or is it that it does not fit your architecture?

Comment: I want to cancel the previous schedule and start new schedule with different interval. However, for timer, there seems no way to do this..so frustrating

Comment: you have to actually cancel the timer and recreate one

Comment: Why? What's the purpose of TimerTask#cancel then?

Answer (score 5):

With the `timer.cancel()` method you can cancels the Timer and all scheduled tasks. (see [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)) or you can call the cancel method on your TimerTask `timertask.cancel()` (see [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html))

If you want to change the scheduled time you should cancel the TimerTask and add a new TimerTask.

Comment: TimerTask#cancel and then Timer#purge() doesn't work. It still runs.

Answer (score 3):

You could look into using a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) instead of a `Timer`.

Usage is pretty straight forward. You create an instance of an executor:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor( 1 );
```

And then when you want to add a task you call:

```
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate( myRunnable, delay, interval, unit );
```

Where `myRunnable` is your task (which implements the `Runnable`-interface), `delay` is how long before the task should be executed the first time, `interval` is time between the execution of the task after first execution. `delay` and `interval` are meassured based on the `unit` parameter, which can be TimeUnit.* (where * is SECONDS, MINUTES, MILLISECONDS etc.).

Then to stop the execution you call:

```
executor.shutdownNow();
```

And then you can re-submit your task with a different interval.

Note: You might need to create a new instance of the executor before resubmitting your task, but I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: how is it different from a timer?

Comment: This link tells you a little about the differences: http://www.dremsus.com/index.php/2011/03/why-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-for-smartfoxserver-2x/ Also this question on Stackoverflow adresses the differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice

Comment: is there anyway that I don't need to shut down the executor or close the timer? I don't want to create a new instance of the executor or timer object...

Comment: You could try experimenting with the `remove(Runnable task)` method of the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. It removes a task, that has not yet been run. The reason I say you should "experiment" is that I'm not sure if it works with regards to task scheduled at a fixed rate.