# Check Database every 5 minutes

Tags: java, database, web-services

I am working on a java web service that is currently connected to a database. Does anyone have an idea how I may query the database every 5 minutes to check for any updates? Any code/information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? It sounds quite vague IMHO

Comment: I just want to constantly check for any updates in the database, in order to synchronize the updated information with a mobile device

Comment: please excuse me if the question was vague, i'm a newbie hehe ;)

Comment: How do you plan to send said information to your device? You state it is a webservice. Thus it relies on a request made. Or you can choose to keep the connection pipe open, but I doubt you do that?

Comment: no in this case, my connection pipe will remain open

Comment: In that case I suppose @ebaxt his answer should be the correct way :-) (Else I had suggest altering your front-end to do a request every 5minutes)

Comment: thank you, I'm trying out different approaches to evaluate which is best( my next approach is altering the front end :D )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              //put query logic here
                }
            }
        }, 10, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Which package does this code `TimeUnit.MINUTES` come from ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are spring framework, there is a library for it. Use

```
@Scheduled(cron = " * 5 *  * * * ") 
public void methodName() {
.........
}
```

Each star represents second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday.

Example patterns:

```
"0 0 * * * *" = the top of every hour of every day.
"*/10 * * * * *" = every ten seconds.
"0 0 8-10 * * *" = 8, 9 and 10 o'clock of every day.
"0 0 6,19 * * *" = 6:00 AM and 7:00 PM every day.
"0 0/30 8-10 * * *" = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, 10:00 and 10:30 every day.
"0 0 9-17 * * MON-FRI" = on the hour nine-to-five weekdays
"0 0 0 25 12 ?" = every Christmas Day at midnight
```

https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Answer (score -1):

Sound like you need to create a new Thread, or new Runnable, and just execute your code, and sleep(5000*60);

Answer (score -1):

If you want this polling to be a constantly running task which runs at a finite interval, then you could probably use the Java TimerTask.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Answer (score -1):

Use java [Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Comment: 1) Should use `Executors` instead of `Timers` and 2) Always link most recent javadoc.

Comment: Timers vs. Executors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice