# Java HashSet Synchronization query

Tags: java, synchronization, hashset

Synchronization question:

```
Set s = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet());
private Object monitor_ = new Object();

//Set has element added in another routine...

//Called by some thread1, thread2, ...
TimerTask run(){ //method which executes every 1 min
  synchronized(monitor_) {
  s.isEmpty()
  // ...
  // waits for 30 seconds
  // JNI call
  // ...
 }
}

//Called by cleanup thread
removecall()
{
 synchronized( monitor_ ) {
   s.remove( something );
 }
}
```

`Problem:`
While TimerTask run method is executing the cleanup thread has to wait. Any efficient way 
to handle this situation withut have to wait. e.g Re-entrant lock

Comment: can you give us the contents of `TimerTask.run()`?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Either you need the 2 operations in the timertask and in the cleanup thread to be synchronized or you don't. If your purpose is only to guarantee a thread safe access to your set, you don't need extra synchronization on top of using a synchronizedSet.

Comment: @assylias yes want safe acces of set, but as per java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet(java.util.Set)
It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned set when iterating over it.

Comment: @orzechowskid the run() calls a JNI method.

Comment: A bit OT, but FYI Timer/TimerTask is semi-deprecated.  Use Executors instead.  See this thread for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice

Answer (score 1):

A concurrent Set might be the solution: [CopyOnWriteArraySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html) or Collections.newSetFromMap([ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)), but it's hard to say given what I know about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate between threads easily if you use a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) as the "messenger". Then you can simply put something inside that queue, for example a string that signalises if the thread is done working, e.g. `public static String DONE = "DONE"`.

Now you only have to poll the queue every once in a while: if its not empty, you can perform any action. This makes your program flow really asynchronous and is very easy to extend.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come to mind:

- When you call `monitor_.wait()`, the thread releases the lock on `monitor_`, so other threads synchornized on `monitor_` can execute
- The other option is that you just wait indefinetely, and override the methods that modify the hashset so that they call `monitor_.notify()`, which would get your `run()` method out of the wait(). This would be much cleaner than that periodic check, and would make the whole system react faster, since changes would be detected immediately instead of every (in average) 30seconds/2

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want **both** your work to be **done concurrently**, `use 2 different objects in the synchronized block.`

eg:

```
Set s = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet());

private Object monitor_1 = new Object();
private Object monitor_2 = new Object();

TimerTask run(){ //method which executes every 1 min
  synchronized(monitor_1) {
  s.isEmpty()

 }
}


removecall()
{
 synchronized( monitor_2) {
   s.remove( pcg );
 }

}
```