# Thread.sleep(); in Java

Tags: java, loops, do-while, thread-sleep

Whenever I use Thread.sleep(); in a do while loop, the hints tell me, "Invoking Thread.sleep in loop can cause performance problems." I have heard this from many other websites and books. What is something I can use instead?

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Delay {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int difficulty;
        difficulty = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How good are you?\n" + "1 = evil genius...\n"
                        + "10 = evil, but not a genius"));
        boolean cont;
        do {
            cont = false;
            System.out.println("12");
            Thread.sleep(500);

            String again = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Play Again?");
            if (again.equals("yes"))
                cont = true;
        } while (cont);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Timer is a little obsolete but it's easier to get a grip on. ScheduledExecutorService is current best practice.

Comment: When you paste code, highlight it all and press "Ctrl + K" to avoid it doing what it has here, not highlighting all of it.

Comment: Why do you think you need to sleep at all?

Comment: @EJP good point - hadn't really thought about _why_ the OP was sleeping the `Thread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try java.util.Timer and/or javax.swing.Timer. Play with them a bit, set initial delay, repetition period, etc. See what suits your needs.

Be sure to check differences between these two timers, for starters take a look at this question: [Why are there two Timer classes in Java(one under javax.swing, one under java.util )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556646/why-are-there-two-timer-classes-in-javaone-under-javax-swing-one-under-java-ut)

Then try [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), as already suggested by @BoristheSpider.

Answer (score -1):

Using `Thread.sleep` to do polling or similar update mechanism is ok approach. It's reasonable for instance if you want to repaint a canvas every 5 milliseconds, then you would use `sleep(5)`. You could also use a hardware timer which will be more exact and relieve the CPU, but the usual approach is exactly `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: No it isn't. In this situation the usual approach, or at least the *correct* approach, is to use a javax.swing.Timer.

Comment: This is a piece of terrible advice. It might be _your_ usual approach but it certainly isn't accepted practice and if one of my developers used it there would be trouble.