# Swing timer vs. util timer

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, timer

I recently started an indie game studio and within the next week we are going to start creating our first game.

The question is "Which timer should I use to create my gametime (gameloop), and why"?

Comment: read Oracle tutorial Concurency in Swing, part Event Dispatch Thread, hint output from Swing Timer notified EDT, not from util.Timer

Comment: You shouldn't use Swing for your GUI, it is outdated. Use JavaFX instead.

Comment: Look at some of the timing frameworks mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16316345/2587435). It'll give you some more options.

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556646/why-are-there-two-timer-classes-in-javaone-under-javax-swing-one-under-java-ut