# Timer implement error

Tags: java, timer

I have error with timer, and I don't know where the error is situated in the code.

ERROR:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       The constructor Timer(int, Player) is undefined
>       The method start() is undefined for the type Timer
>
> at Player.(Player.java:12)
>
> at Game.main(Game.java:11)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.Timer;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Player extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
Timer t = new Timer(5, this); // Error (LINE 12)
double x = 0; double velX = 2;
double y = 0; double velY = 2;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,40,40);
    g2.fill(circle);
    t.start(); // error
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    x += velX;
    y += velY;
    repaint();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've imported `java.util.Timer`. Maybe you meant `javax.swing.Timer`?

You can google for more info, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556646/why-are-there-two-timer-classes-in-javaone-under-javax-swing-one-under-java-ut) is a pretty good explanation of the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
import java.util.Timer;
```

with

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such constructor for the `java.util.Timer` class, and no such method either.

Ensure that you are importing the correct class in the import declarations above the class header. You may mean `java.swing.Timer`.

If so, `java.swing.Timer` won't get imported by `java.swing.*`, since you have already imported a class of the same name (`java.util.Timer`). Remove the `java.util.Timer` import and it should all work.

Source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_timer.htm