# How to add timer to JLabel when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am creating a simple stopwatch program with 3 buttons ( Start, Stop and Reset) and a simple JLabel to display the time. I am adding an action listener to the start button so when the button is clicked, the timer starts the clock on the label.

However, when I try to add the timer variable inside the button event, it doesn't allow me to do so. Can anyone suggest what I did wrong or how to improve it?

Code:

```
public class GuiStopwatch {





    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stopwatch");

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
          JPanel panel = new JPanel();

          panel.setLayout(null);

          JButton Startbtn = new JButton("START");  
          JButton Stopbtn = new JButton("STOP");
          JButton Reset = new JButton("RESET");
          JLabel time = new JLabel("Time shows here");
             panel.add(Startbtn);
             panel.add(Stopbtn);
            panel.add(Reset);
            panel.add(time);
             Startbtn.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 35);
             Stopbtn.setBounds(50, 200, 100, 35);
             Reset.setBounds(50, 250, 100, 35);
             time.setBounds(50, 350, 100, 35);
             time.setBackground(Color.black);
             time.setForeground(Color.red);
             frame.add(panel);


             Startbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Timer timer = new Timer(1,new ActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    })

                }
            });
```

EDIT:

The error is it says there is no constructor defined for Timer(int, ActionListener).

Comment: @markspace I see. I suppose the  actionperformed is not needed when declaring the Timer timer variable?

Comment: What error message are you seeing? Post that in your question as an [edit] please.

Comment: No I was wrong.  The syntax is still too hard to parse (read) with those nested anonymous classes.  I'd make separate classes (not anonymous) so that it's easier to read the syntax there.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels See my edited

Comment: You're importing the wrong Timer class. Not `import java.util.Timer;` but rather `import javax.swing.Timer`

Comment: Either that or you have your own class somewhere that you've given the name `Timer` and are confusing the compiler.

Comment: What is the purpose of java.util.Timer compared to swing.Timer?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I notcied that I can't use two imports of the Timer you mentioned at the same time. Why is that?  Anyway, I imported the wrong Timer . You can post your answer below.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate. [Some differences between the two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556646/why-are-there-two-timer-classes-in-javaone-under-javax-swing-one-under-java-ut)