# TimerTask() not doing what was supposed to, only printing one time

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Timer ttt = new Timer();
        TimerTask test = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("IN");
                        }
                 };

        ttt.schedule(test, 1000);
}
```

This was supposed to print "IN" every second but it is only printing one time. Any tips? Thank you

What

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the one-shot version of `schedule`. Simply use the [overloaded version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) that accepts an interval period:

```
ttt.schedule(test, 0, 1000);
```

---

*Aside:* The newer [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) is preferred over `java.util.Timer`. Timer has only one executing thread, so long-running task can delay other tasks. An `ExecutorService` can operate using a thread pool. Discussed more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice)