# Set off a scheduled event at a given time?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I'm writing a Java-based shell-type... erm.. *thing*. Anyway, one of the commands I am implementing is a `schedule` command, where you can tell it the time you want to run the command and it waits for the time, runs the command once, and exits. However, I can't figure out how to get it to check the time - I implemented one that just checks if the dates are equal, did a little research to see if a better solution existed, then found that apparently `Date` is not a good thing to use. What should I do?

MCVE:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Scheduler extends Thread {
    private Date goAt;
    private String command;
    public Scheduler(Date goAt, String command) {
        this.goAt = goAt;
        this.command = command;
    }
    public void start() {
        super.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        while (!goAt.equals(new Date())) {} //Wait until the dates are equal
        runCommand(command); //In the real thing, this runs the command.
    }
    public void runCommand(String command) {
        System.out.println("Command: " + command);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scheduler task = new Scheduler(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000));
        task.start();
    }
}
```

I would like this to be done without using third-party libraries, or libraries that must be downloaded separately. If there is no way to do so, then I will accept answers with a third-party library, but preference goes to solutions without them. Also ideal would be if answers allowed me to directly specify a time to run the command, rather than calculating the relative time difference and using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the builtin `java.util.Timer` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to schedule code to run at a given future time or after a given delay.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)/[TimerTasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) to schedule commands - [here is a tutorial](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html).

Another option is to put the commands in a [DelayQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) (with the delay set to the time that the task should fire), then use a consumer thread to repeatedly call `take` on the queue and fire the commands it removes.

In terms of third party libraries, [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) is a good scheduler.

Comment: Timers can get the job done but they have issues to watch out for.  It's recommended to use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html instead.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice for the explanation.

Comment: Dead link for the primary part of the answer. Please provide example code in the answer.