# What to consider when writing a java program that is supposed to run 'forever'

Tags: java

I have to write a program that is thought to run 'forever' , meaning that it won't terminate regularly. Up until now I always wrote programs that would run and be terminated at the end of the day. The program has to do some synchronizations, pause for *n* minutes and than sync again.

AFAIK there should be no problem with my current implementation and it should theoretically run just fine, but I'm lacking any real-world experience.

*So are there any 'patterns' or best practices for writing very robust and resource efficient java programs that have a very long runtime? What could be possible problems after for example a month/year of runtime?*

Some background :

- Java : 1.7 but compiled down to 1.5
- OS : Windows (exact version is not certain yet)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google keywords: `java daemon process`.

Comment: You need to consider whether the program needs to be able to update itself while running.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a brain dump of all the things I've had to keep in mind when writing this kind of app.

**Avoid Memory Leaks**

I had an app that runs once at mid day, every day, and in that I had a `FileWriter`. I wasn't closing that properly, and then we started wondering why our virtual machine was going into melt down after a few weeks. Memory leaks can come in the form of anyhing really, with one of the most common examples being that you don't `de-reference` an object appropriately. For example, using a class's field as a method of temporary storage. Often the class persists, and so does the reference. This leaves you with objects, sitting in memory and doing nothing.

**Use the right kind of Scheduler**

I used a java `Timer` in that app, and later I learnt that it's better to use a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) when another app was changing the System clock. So if you plan on keeping it completely Java based, I would strongly recommend using that over a Timer for all of the reasons detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice).

**Be mindful of memory usage and your environment**

If your app is loading large amounts of data each and every day, and you have other apps running on the same server, you may want to be careful about the timing. For example, say at mid day, three of the apps run their scheduled operation, I would say running it at *any other time* would probably be a smart move. Be mindful of the environment in which you're executing your code in.

**Error handling**

You probably want to configure your app to let you know if something has gone wrong, without the app breaking down. If it's running at a certain time every few hours, that means people are probably depending on it, so I would have a function in your Java code that sends out an email to you, detailing the nature of the exception.

**Make it configurable**

Again, if it needs to run at various points in the day, you don't want to have to pull the thing down for a few hours to work out some minor changes to your code. Instead, port it into a java Properties file, or into an XML Config (or really, whatever). The advantage of this is that you can update your program and get it up and running before anyone really noticed the difference.

**Be afraid of the `static` keyword**

That bad boy will make objects persist, even when you destroy their parent reference. It is the mother of all memory leaks if you are not careful with it. It's fine for constants, and things that you know don't need to change and need to exist within the project to run well, but if you're using it for random values inside a project, you're going to quickly wonder why your app is crashing every few hours rather than `syncing`.

Props to @X86 for reminding me of that one.

Comment: and -- Use the "static" keyword judiciously... You would not want to over encumber the JVM with your static fields.

Comment: "That bad boy will make objects persist, even when you destroy their parent reference. It is the mother of all memory leaks if you are not careful with it." - Very funny...  You should write a book... :P

Comment: @Michal -Good lord how did I miss this one - :P

Comment: Is there a problem with `static` methods, too? Or does this hint only apply to fields?

Comment: Static methods are loaded when the class is loaded. Following the logic of minimising the amount of memory you use, it's probably recommended to minimize them, because they aren't taken out of memory until the virtual machine exists, which in this case is never.

Answer (score 4):

Memory leaks are likely to be the biggest problem.  Ensure that there are no long-term references held after an iteration of your logic.  Even a relatively small object being referenced forever, will exhaust the memory *eventually* (and worse, it's going to be harder to detect during testing if the growth rate is 1GB/month).  One approach that may help is using the snapshot functionality of profilers: take a snapshot during the pause, let the sync run a few times, and take another snapshot.  Comparing these should show the delta between the synchronizations, which should hopefully be zero.

Cache maintenance is another issue.  The overall size of a cache needs to be strictly limited (whereas often you can get away without in short-running programs, because everything seen will be small enough to not cause problems).  Equally it's more important to do cache-invalidation properly - broadly speaking, everything that gets cached *will* become stale at some point while your program is still running, and you need to be able to detect this and take appropriate action.  This can be tricky depending on where the golden source of the cached data is.

The last thing I'll mention is exception-handling.  For short-running processes, it's often enough to simply let the process die when an exception is encountered, so the issue can be dealt with, and the app rerun.  With a long-running process you'll likely need to be more defensive than this.  Consider running parts of your program in threads, which can be restarted* if/when they fail.  You may need a supervisor-type module, which checks that everything else is still heartbeating and reboots it if not.  If appropriate to your structure, this is anecdotally a lot easier to achieve with actors-style libraries rather than Java's standard executors.  And if it's at all possible, you may want to have hooks (perhaps exposed over JMX/MBeans) that let you modify the behaviour somewhat, to allow a short-term hack/workaround to be affected without having to bring the process down.  Though this requires quite some amount of foresight to predict exactly what's going to go wrong in several months...

*or rather, the job can be restarted in another thread

Comment: Thanks for also covering exceptions, I had something like this in my mind,too.