# Trigger a run() method of Timer of Java manually

Tags: java

So, I set my timer:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        ...
    }
}, 5, 5);
```

so I want to trigger this `run()` for testing something, not wait until it gets triggered. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why using executors or threads? **its not enough* to run method**? :)

```
// define task 
TimerTask = tt new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        ...
    }
};


// schedule 
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt,int,int);

// run as any other method :) 
tt.run();
```

*when run is not enought?  when we can't or don't want to block the current thread!

Answer (score 1):

Just create the `Runnable` object before (not using anonymus class) and use it to create a new `Thread` and then start it.

Something like this

```
   Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /*impl*/
        }
    };

    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Comment: Why is unnice ? I thought you want to test something.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
// single thread pool - you can use any other scheduled thread pool
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        /*impl*/
    }
}, 5, 5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: As a side note:``ScheduledExecutorService`` is to be preferred over ``Timer``: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice