# TimerTask vs Timer vs Thread?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to show Date and time continuously on a JLabel. So on the last tutorial I've watched.the speaker said "You must Use this threads whenever necessary because it takes memory in your program".

So I search other alternatives and i find Timer and TimerTask which is the most efficient way to use on the long run of the program?

Comment: For code like this that is altering Swing Components, you should use javax.swing.Timer

Comment: can you elaborate more? why javax.swing.Timer?

Comment: a third option is to use a ScheduledExecutorService. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice

Comment: swings Timer should be used because it allows you to directly interact with the GUI objects because it runs in the GUI thread. If you call methods of GUI objects from outside the GUI thread, the application might crash.

Comment: @ControlAltDel is this not a web?

Comment: Thanks to all response :)

Comment: I'd second using a ScheduledExecutorService. It's basically a modern, more generic replacement for Timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Timer is used to run a task (i.e: TimerTask) on an interval, after a delay, or a combination of the two. In your case, you can use something like this:

```
   java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
//            do task
        }
    }, 0, 1000);  //updates every second
```

Note that in order to update a Swing component in a thread other than the Swing thread, you'll need to use a SwingWorker (see [Swing Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)), or user a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead. The code below is using a Swing timer to update the label with a new date every second:

```
javax.swing.Timer timer1 = new javax.swing.Timer(0, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText(new Date());
        }
    });

    timer1.setRepeats(true);
    timer1.setDelay(1000);
```

I haven't tested this, so you may need to tweak it a little to work for you.