# Method called repeatedly at 10 second intervals

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I want to implement a function which will be refreshed in every 10 second in server side using java - netbeans

I have a counter in my function which should be refreshed depend on the time .

Comment: You could use a `java.util.Timer` but better to use a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice)

Answer (score 1):

Look into using the Java Timer class. This class can execute a TimerTask for a specified interval.

**Documentation:**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

**Example:**

```
 import java.util.Timer;  //Be sure to import the correct Timer
 ...
 Timer timer = new Timer();
 timer.schedule(new CustomTimerTask(), seconds * 10000);
```

Your CustomTimerTask will be a class which extends TimerTask and implements a run method. The run method will be called every `10000` miliseconds as specified.

**Complete Example:**

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm