# Threads running at specific time intervals for a specific time in JAVA

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-sleep

I want to use the below mentioned operations in JAVA for android development.

1. For 30 Seconds ,Run a Function F1() every 1 second (resulting in 30 F1 calls).
2. Run a Thread t1 forever

The above steps should execute sequentially.
I Have tried with `ExecutorService`but with no success.

**This is my code for reference**

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
final int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        F1();
    }
});

for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
    executor.submit(t1);
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

executor.shutdown();
//Step 2 (THe Second Thread)

h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        AnotherFunction()
        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: Ah "it doesn't work" any more specific than that?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, `ExecutorService` is more preferable for such operations. Here is a good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice) describing the differences and features of `Timer` and `ExecutorService`.

As for your question directly - it can be implemented in such way:

```
// here are Runnables with test logic
Runnable foo = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(">>>", "foo");
        onTaskFinished();
    }
};

Runnable longRunning = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.d(">>>", "longRunning started");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Log.d(">>>", "longRunning finished");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

// and here is valuable logic
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
ScheduledFuture<?> schedulerHandler;
volatile AtomicInteger tasksNum = new AtomicInteger(0);

private synchronized void onTaskFinished(){
    if(tasksNum.incrementAndGet() >= 30){
        scheduler.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                schedulerHandler.cancel(true);
            }
        });
        scheduler.execute(longRunning);
    }
}
```

And then to start operation just invoke this command:

```
schedulerHandler = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(foo, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask` classes

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing what I think you're doing you can  do as **@erosb** hinted, use `Timer` and `TimerTask` to schedule method executions at a fixed rate.

The following should work for you.

```
final int DELAY_BEFORE_START = 0;
final int RATE = 1000; 

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        F1();
    }
}, DELAY_BEFORE_START, RATE);
```