# How to check smartcard presence by polling

Tags: java, multithreading, polling

I need to check the presence of a smartcard in my Java application to generate something like an "event" on smartcard removal.

I have a simple method to test it:

```
public boolean isCardIn(){};
```

What is the best way to poll this?
In this case, should I use a `java.utils.Timer.Timer()` or an `ExecutorService()`?

---

This my current implementation:

To start polling

```
checkTimer.schedule(new CheckCard(), delay,delay);
```

And this is the timer's execution:

```
private class CheckCard extends TimerTask{   

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            if(!SmartcardApi.isCardIn(slot)){
                 // fire event
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a look on StackOverflow some more because I think your question's been answered:
[Java Timer vs ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice)

I think generally, it's better to use newer API, which in this case is the `ExecutorService`. Here's how I'd do it:

## Main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    SmartCardApi smartCardApi = new SmartCardApi();

    // Polling job.
    Runnable job = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Is card in slot? " + smartCardApi.isCardInSlot());
        }
    };
    
    // Schedule the check every second.
    scheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(job, 1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    
    // After 3.5 seconds, insert the card using the API.
    Thread.sleep(3500);
    smartCardApi.insert(1);
    
    // After 4 seconds, eject the card using the API.
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    smartCardApi.eject();

    // Shutdown polling job.
    scheduledExecutor.shutdown();
    
    // Verify card status.
    System.out.println("Program is exiting. Is card still in slot? " + smartCardApi.isCardInSlot());
}
```

## SmartCardApi

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class SmartCardApi {
    private AtomicBoolean inSlot = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    
    public boolean isCardInSlot() {
        return inSlot.get();
    }
    
    public void insert(int slot) {
        System.out.println("Inserted into " + slot);
        inSlot.set(true);
    }

    public void eject() {
        System.out.println("Ejected card.");
        inSlot.set(false);
    }
}
```

## Program Output

```
Is card in slot? false
Is card in slot? false
Is card in slot? false
Inserted into 1
Is card in slot? true
Is card in slot? true
Is card in slot? true
Is card in slot? true
Ejected card.
Program is exiting. Is card still in slot? false
```

In this case, I'm using a simple `Runnable` which could call another object in order to fire its `event`. You could also use a `FutureTask` instead of this `Runnable`, but that's just based on your preference for *how* you want this event to fired..

Comment: I want to focus my question on polling.

Comment: I've changed my answer to show how you'd use it. As for the why, the `ExecutorService` is a newer API. I read that there can be issues with `TimerTask`s and its execution time in relation to your system clock, but I've never used either of them personally. The code snippet above is just _one_ way you could use the `ExecutorService` IMO.